# CakePHP 2.3.1 updateAll query not working

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am not able to update records in CakePHP 2.3.1

Query:

`$this -> Staff -> updateAll(array('Staff.last_login' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')), array('Staff.id' => $staff['Staff']['id']));`

Error:

`Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use`

Comment: will you please check with core level 2 to print what exactly sql query is run ?

Comment: Isn't `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` returning a string?
You need to escape those manually in order to avoid them being treated as functions etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I fixed the issue by using `'NOW()'` instead of date()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions :

```
The $fields array accepts SQL expressions. 
Literal values should be quoted manually using Sanitize::escape().
```

You can use

```
NOW()
```

But, in your case, it would also work with the quoting:

```
"'" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$this->Staff->updateAll(array('Staff.last_login' => "'$date'"), array('Staff.id' => $staff['Staff']['id']));
```