# CakePHP - updateAll fills 0000-00-00 in datefield

Tags: mysql, cakephp

In an application I'm creating, there is a point where alot of records are being made. These records calculate the amount of money created. There is a date which will display the last update-date.
However, whenever there is an update, the date does not change. It will be saved as 0000-00-00 even though I've put it in correctly.

Here's a snippit of my code:

`$date = date('Y-m-d');`

```
// based on existion, update or create the commission
                    if ( $commission_exists > 0) {

                    //exists, so needs to be updated instead of created
                    $this->Commission->updateAll(array( // THIS ONE DOES NOT WORK
                        'commission_rel_client' => $position['Position']['position_rel_client'],
                        'commission_rel_account' => $position['Position']['position_id'],
                        'commission_date' => $date,
                        'commission_value01' => '1.23',
                        'commission_value02' => '4.56',
                        'commission_value03' => '7.89',
                        'commission_value04' => '0.12',
                        'commission_value05' => '3.45',
                        'commission_value06' => '6.78',
                        'commission_value07' => '9.01',
                        'commission_value08' => '1.23',
                        'commission_value09' => '4.56',
                        'commission_value10' => '7.89',
                        'commission_value11' => '0.12',
                        'commission_value12' => '3.45',
                        'commission_value13' => '6.78',
                        'commission_value14' => '9.01',
                        'commission_total' => '200'
                    ), array('commission_rel_account' => $position['Position']['position_id']));
                }
                else {
                    // save commission record
                    $this->Commission->create();
                    $this->Commission->save(array( // THIS ONE WORKS
                        'commission_rel_client' => $position['Position']['position_rel_client'],
                        'commission_rel_account' => $position['Position']['position_id'],
                        'commission_date' => $date,
                        'commission_value01' => '1.23',
                        'commission_value02' => '4.56',
                        'commission_value03' => '7.89',
                        'commission_value04' => '0.12',
                        'commission_value05' => '3.45',
                        'commission_value06' => '6.78',
                        'commission_value07' => '9.01',
                        'commission_value08' => '1.23',
                        'commission_value09' => '4.56',
                        'commission_value10' => '7.89',
                        'commission_value11' => '0.12',
                        'commission_value12' => '3.45',
                        'commission_value13' => '6.78',
                        'commission_value14' => '9.01',
                        'commission_total' => '200'
                    ));
                }
```

Don't mind the values, just test-data. I just wonder what's 'wrong' with my code, as it seems perfectly fine to me.
I've also tried updateField, which worked, but can't be used here due my records getting filtered on a certain field and not the id (yea, sounds strange, i know. Don't question my dumb logic.).

Comment: What's the datatype of the commission_date?

Comment: @Dezigo it has the type: Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions) you should try to define the date between quotes

```
$this->Ticket->updateAll(
    array('Ticket.status' => "'" . $data . "'"),
    array('Ticket.customer_id' => 453)
);
```

Comment: That's only for a string field? I'm handeling a date-field.

Comment: It should work with date fields also. [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008714/cakephp-2-3-1-updateall-query-not-working)